# PHP $_POST always empty

Tags: javascript, php

Stumped, var-dump($_POST) always returns array[0] {} PHP mail though always succeeds. Variables in html side are what I expect when viewed in the debugger. Fails with both register_globals on and off.

```
 <!-- html code (in contact.php) -->
<form name="hhcform" method="POST" action="sendmail.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();"      enctype="text/plain"> 
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" size="25">
<span id="firstnameErr" style="color:red">*</span>
<br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" size="25">
<span id="lastnameErr" style="color:red">*</span>
<br><br>
Email Address: <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="" size="25">
<span id="emailErr" style="color:red">*</span>
<br><br>
Select a Topic: <span id="topicErr" style="color:red">*</span><br>
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Insurance"> Accepted Insurance<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Hours"> Office Hours<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Refills"> Prescription Refills<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Patients"> Accepting New Patients<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Website"> Website Issues<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="Other"> Other<br><br>
    </div>
Comments: <span id="commentErr" style="color:red">*</span><br>
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="25"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="ClearErrors();"><br><br>
</form>
```

PHP code (in sendmail.php)

```
 <?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname =  $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $recipient = "emailaddress@domainbame.com";
    $mailheader = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
    if(mail($recipient, $topic, $comments, $mailheader))
    {
        echo "Email Sent, Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact.php' 
        style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return to Contact Us Form</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Email failed to send" . "-" . "<a href='contact.php' 
        style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return to Contact Us Form</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can we see your `validateForm` function?

Comment: My first advice would be to use your deveoper tools. Keep them open and submit your form. On sendmail.php, you should see the request data your form has passed. If you see none, something is blocking your form from sending the data. If you see it, something is blocking the data being picked up server side

Comment: As @Sean said you should use your developer tools to see if your web browser is sending the data in the first place. For all we know your `ValidateForm()` could be fubarring everything and everyone is none-the-wiser

Comment: `enctype="text/plain"` is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Take out

```
enctype="text/plain" in the form, this should fix the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with your enctype

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

Try

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

instead, unless you have a good reason for using text/plain.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. Once I removed the enctype="text/plain" the array was filled with the data I expected. Issue resolved.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! Don't forget to mark Abhik's answer as correct so that others will know what to do if they come across the same issue in the future. Cheers